# Analyzing apache access logs with elasticsearch Watcher

Tags: access-log, elasticsearch-watcher

I am using the ELK Stack to analyze logs and I need to analyze and detect anomalies of apache access logs. What can I analyze with apache access logs and how should I give the conditions with curl -XPUT to Watcher?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found it already, there's a decent tutorial at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/watcher-1.0/watch-log-data.html.  It provides a basic example of creating a log watch.

You can analyze/watch anything that you can query in Elasticsearch.  It's just a matter of formatting the query with the correct JSON syntax.  The guide for crafting the conditions is at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/watcher-1.0/condition.html.

You'll also want to look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/watcher-1.0/actions.html to get an idea of the possible actions Watcher can take when a query meets a condition.

As far as the post to Watcher, each watch is essentially a JSON object.  Because they can get pretty elaborate, I have found that it's best to create a file for each watch you want to create, and post them like this:

```
curl -XPUT http://my_elasticsearch:9200/_watcher/watch/my_watch_name -d @/path/to/my_watch_name.json
```

my_watch_name.json should have these basic elements (as described in the first link above):

```
{
  "trigger" : { ... },
  "input" : { ... },
  "condition" : { ... },
  "actions" : { ... }
}
```

The actions section is going to be specific to your use case, but here's a basic example of the other sections that I'm using successfully:

```
{
  "trigger" : {
      "schedule" : { "interval" : "5m" }
  },
  "input" : {
    "search" : {
      "request" : {
        "indices" : [ "logstash" ],
        "body" : {
          "query" : {
            "filtered" : {
              "query" : {
                "match" : { "message" : "error" }
              },
              "filter" : {
                "range" : { "@timestamp" : { "gte" : "now-5m" } }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition" : {
    "compare" : { "ctx.payload.hits.total" : { "gt" : 0 } }
  },
  "actions" : {
    ...
  }
}
```